# What is the right approach for assemblying module resources in Maven project?

Tags: maven-2, maven-assembly-plugin

I have a project structure like

```
module-a/src/main/java
module-a/src/main/styles
module-distribution/src/main/assembly
```

module-distribution depends on module-a, and they both share parent pom and are included as modules in that parent pom.

The idea is to have an assembly layout like

```
my-final-assembly/lib
my-final-assembly/styles
```

Where lib directory contains all project artifacts including dependencies (i.e. module-a.jar and its dependency jars), and module-a.jar should not contain its styles directory in it. styles directory should reside in my-final-assembly/styles.

I can fill out the lib directory easily including

```
<dependencySet>
    <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
</dependencySet>
```

in my assembly file. But what about module-a/src/main/styles? 
I can

1. include it in module-a artifact (it would reside in module-a.jar)
2. not include it in module-a.jar.

Sure thing, both 1) and 2) are not valid for me. In first case I have to somehow extract styles directory out of my module-a.jar. In second case styles directory would not be copied at all, as  copies the artifact only, not entire target folder.

I have a last resort of creating an individual module for styles directory contents, and make module-a depend on it, but that looks like an overkill for me. Though it would be easy to tune my assembly file to get what I want in that case. But a separate module for a bunch of fonts and xmls that a sole module needs? That would be sad, though I am ready if that is what you call Maven Way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somehow, you have to put the styles in an artifact at some point to be able to pull and include them in the "final-assembly". I can think of 3 approaches:

The first approach is what you're describing: putting the styles in a separate module and have bot module-a and module-distribution depend on it (actually, I don't really understand why module-a has a dependency on it since you're not using them/including them in the module-a artifact but this is left at your discretion).

The second approach would be to keep your current structure but to create an intermediate assembly for module-a. This assembly would contain module-a.jar **and** the styles (or maybe just the styles). Then, in module-distribution, you would pull this assembly, unpack it, and create the "final-assembly".

A third approach would be similar to the previous one except that the final-assembly would be created directly from module-a (it's not clear if module-distribution has other dependencies than module-a; if it doesn't, then you could do everything from module-a).

Comment: Thanks for hint, Pascal!
The project has a bunch of dependencies, module-a is not the only one, thus I have chosen second approach.
I pack module-a.zip with assembly id "with-styles":
module-a-with-styles.zip/lib/module-a.jar,
module-a-with-styles.zip/styles
Then after some tweaks in final-assembly.xml I get what I expected. 
BTW, is it a common practice to post thorough details of my working solution as an answer to the question, so that everyone could see it? This comment area does not allow for pretty formatting

Comment: @zamza You're welcome. Regarding your question, your implementation might be a bit specific but if you think that it could be reused by someone else, don't hesitate. Specific or not, it won't hurt.